# Hosting Apple verification file with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm using NextJS.

As per [here](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/payment-request-button), I need to host a file on my app.

Specifically, it needs to be hosted at:

`https://app.blah.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`

What is the best way to serve this file from that folder? The URL has to be exactly as above.

When I try and put it in a folder at top level called `.well-known`, it doesn't work. I suspect because it's not being served when the app is actually built.

Conversely, `localhost/static/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association` works fine if I put the file in there.

So, how can I do what I need to do here?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Anything in Next.js `public` folder will become accessible at root. So put the file in `/public/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association` and it will be accessible at `yourdomain.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association`.